# Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?.Type' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>.Type) to expected argument type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

Getting this error on `size = text.boundingRectWithSize`

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?.Type' (aka
>   'Optional>.Type) to expected argument
>   type '[String : AnyObject]?'

```
func heightOfString(text: NSString!, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat{
    var ch:CGFloat!
    var size:CGSize = CGSizeMake(width, CGFloat.max)

    var tdic:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [font, NSFontAttributeName], forKeys: [])
    size = text.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading , attributes: [String : AnyObject]?, context: nil).size
    ch = size.height
    return ch

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass an empty dictionary for the attributes, use `[:]`

```
size = text.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading , attributes: [:], context: nil).size
```

Comment: Could also pass in nil.